# On-demand hide or show block in responsive view with CSS

Tags: css

I have always found replies to my questions here even before I asked them. Right now I am facing a problem regarding the responsive adaption of a site I created (www.cichlidae.com) that led me to post this question after several years of just reading.

In my site, when a break-point is reached, a left side menu bar seen in all pages hides. I would like this bar to be displayed over the content on demand, when a mobile device is used. I was able to make the top menu bar adapt responsively to display and the #bar to hide.

For trying to display the left bar menu (with a div labelled “bar”) I used the following CSS code:

```
#bar {
    display:none;
}
#bar ~ .display_bar:focus {
    display:block;
}
```

I set `#bar` first as that is the order in which the code for #bar loads once the page is loaded (I tried .display_bar:focus ~#bar as well). I created an icon displayed in mobile view to activate the display switch:

`<div class=\"display_bar\">Some graphic</div>`

I have tried all combinations and browsers, validated CSS and HTML, but the bar just won’t show when the icon is clicked on. I have tried with a single `<p>` tag with a class name instead of `#bar` but it ignores it as well. One of the example of pages could be seen in the URL:

http://www.cichlidae.com/index_catalog.php

What could I be doing wrong? I need the left bar to show on demand when in mobile view, preferably just with CSS. Thanks so much for any help you could provide me.

The relevant HTML code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>All cichlid species - Cichlid ..</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design/styles/indexstyle.css" title="Cichlid ...">
    ...
</head>

<body>

<!-- left frame -->
<div id="bar">

    <a href="default.php"><img src="design/graphics/logos/logo_menu.jpg" width="200" height="165" alt="Cichlid Room Companion"></a><br><br>
    ...
    <div style="padding-left:10px;">

    <h3>Catalog</h3>

    <a href="species_classification.php">Classification</a><br>
    ....

    </div>
</div>

<!-- right frame -->
<div id="main">
<div id="canvas" style="max-width:800px">

    <!-- Menu bar -->
    <ul id="menu" class="r-hide">

        <li><a href="default.php" target="_top" class="drop">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown_3columns">

            <h2>Welcome ...</h2>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="r-only">
    <div id="r-navigation-menu">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r-navigation-button">
        <ul class="r-menu-items">
            <h2>News</h2>
            <li><a href="whatsnew.php" target="_top">What's new</a></li>
            ....
        </ul>

        <label for="r-navigation-button" id="r-navigation-label">
            <div class="r-drop-icon">
                <img src="design/graphics/icons/menu-hamburger.png" class="icon" width="32" height="32" alt="">
                ...
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="display_bar" tabindex="-1"><img src="design/graphics/icons/menu-collapse.png" class="icon" width="32" height="32" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly, you've got the selector a bit backwards. It should probably be `.display_bar:focus ~ #bar`. Could you post the relevant HTML around the `#bar` element as well?

Comment: Maybe add `tabindex="-1"` to the `<div class="display_bar">`.  That way it can have a focus. If focusing does not work, you could use a `checkbox`, `label`, and `:checked`

Comment: Along the lines of Jesse's comment, your current CSS is telling the `.display_bar` element to have the `display: block;` property when it is focused and occurs after a `#bar` element as its sibling.

Comment: Thanks. The <div id="bar"> appears in the code before the <div class="display_bar">, that is what I thought #bar .display_bar:focus was needed instead of  .display_bar:focus ~ #bar (which I also tried). Thanks @UndoingTec I tried tabindex="-1" as well to no avail.

Comment: Like I said before, you can try using a CSS trick with `checkbox`.  I used it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undoingtech/fwsnbsf9/).  That is all the advice I can give without answering the question, and I'd rather not answer without seeing your HTML.

Comment: @UndoingTech Thanks for your reply. I use checkbox for the menu bar on top of each page, I tried checkbox as well for #bar but would not work. I am mystified about this, you can see the HMTL code in any www.cichlidae.com page for example [link](http://www.cichlidae/com/index_catalog.php). If you resize your browser window you will see the three dots contextual menu icon that it is supposed to display the #bar div, it just doesn't... I appreciate your help

Comment: From your link, I cannot see any element that has the class `display_bar`, and the only sibling to `div#bar` I can see is `div#main`.  I never saw the "three dots" either.  Were you referring to the hamburger icon?  This is why you post the HTML.  Your post shows what to focus on (and can often make you think through the problem).

Comment: @UndoingTech  I am sorry it could have been the cache (I deleted it) I thought the HTML would be too long to post here (it is in line 368), I edited my question with the relevant HTML part.  It shows as "<div class="display_bar" tabindex="-1">image link</div>". In display it is just below the hamburger icon. I appreciate it

Comment: Looks like `div.display_bar` is a child of `div#main`.  `div#bar` and `div.display_bar` need to be siblings for your CSS to work.

Comment: @UndoingTech  Thank you for looking into it. I have made the divs siblings (removing div.display_bar out of div#main), somehow still it does not work. I tried also with a different tag to display (p.bar instead of div#bar) to see if different identifiers (id versus class) could play a role, I also placed div.display_bar above div#bar in the code to see if order could matter but to no avail. I tried with both firefox and chrome

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ppqvdhke/).  I used `:focus` on `div.display_bar`.  Since I don't have access to your image, I put in alternate text.  If you click on the text, the `div#bar` will show.  Is this the effect you were looking for?

Comment: @UndoingTech Yes absolutely! I used the your CSS code and added the link to the page [link](http://www.cichlidae.com/index_catalog.php) with the div.display_bar above the div#bar. The three points show to the left of the hamburger icon when in responsive view. They still don't work!!

Comment: The HTML and CSS for `.display_bar` and `#bar` are working.  Your fixed `div#main` is covering both of them, so you can't click and focus on it.  The browser thinks you are clicking on `div#main`.  You can see this by using FF or Chrome's developer tools `Ctrl+Shift+I`.  At the top left of the developer tools, there is a selector tool that allows you to inspect an element on the page by clicking it.  It is very useful.

Comment: Also, since you might have had cashe issues earlier, an easy way to clear that is `Ctrl+Shift+Delete`.  ALSO, once you get your code working you should answer this question with relevant code, a little explanation, and a code snippet demo.  Keeps good, clear documentation for this site and helps those who face a similar problem to yours in the future.

Comment: Thank you @UndoingTech, I will fix the code and post the answer here. I very much appreciate it